# Can I use GWT HTTP request to read a text file from a website?

Tags: java, gwt, httprequest

I have created a [GWT Starter Project](http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html#compiling) and I wanted to use an [HTTP Request](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests) to read a text file from another site.

I put this code in the entry point method `onModuleLoad()`:

```
String url = "http://www.textfiles.com/100/apples.txt";
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);

try {
    Request myrequest = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {

        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        // Couldn't connect to server (could be
        // timeout, SOP violation, etc.)
        }
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                Label l = new Label();
                l.setText("Response: " + response.getText());
                RootPanel.get().add(l);
            }
            else {
                // Handle the error. Can get the status
                // text from response.getStatusText()
                Label l = new Label();
                l.setText("Error. getText() = " + response.getText() 
                    + " Status text = "
                    + response.getStatusText()
                    + ". Code: "
                    + response.getStatusCode());
                RootPanel.get().add(l);
            }
        }
    });
}
catch (RequestException e) {
    // Couldn't connect to server
}
```

The error block is always executed and `response.getStatusCode()` is 0. `response.getText()` and `response.getStatusText()` return blank text. Can GWT HTTP Request be used to read text files, or should I use another method?

Comment: Are you making a request to a different domain?

Comment: @Fedy2 Yes, I've tried other sites but get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make HTTP requests to different domains because of the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).